# Spring MVC Authentication Success Handler and Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, forms-authentication

I have made a user login interface where the user gets authenticated using `spring security`.

I have made an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` which redirects the user to a new page.

I also want to implement a `loginController` in order to get the name of user logged in as well as displaying error messages for wrong credentials. Here is my `Handler` code :

```
public class MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

protected MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
    handle(request, response, authentication);
    clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
}

protected void handle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
    final String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication);

    if (response.isCommitted()) {
        logger.debug("Response has already been committed. Unable to redirect to " + targetUrl);
        return;
    }

    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
}

protected String determineTargetUrl(final Authentication authentication) {
    boolean isUser = false;
    boolean isAdmin = false;
    final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
    for (final GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
        if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_USER")) {
            isUser = true;
            break;
        } else if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            isAdmin = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isUser) {
        return "/static_htm.html";
    } else if (isAdmin) {
        return "/console.html";
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}
```

And my `controller` code :

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome(ModelMap model, Principal principal ) {

    String name = principal.getName();
    model.addAttribute("username", name);
    model.addAttribute("message", "Spring Security Hello World");
    return "static_htm";                 //page after successful login

}

@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(ModelMap model) {

    return "login";                      //login page

}

@RequestMapping(value="/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginerror(ModelMap model) {

    //String errormessage = resources.getMessage("login.error", null, null);
    model.addAttribute("error", "true");
    return "login";                      //login page

}

}
```

The handler works fine but I am not able to get the user name as well as the error message. What should I do to make both the `handler` and `controller` work together ?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I presume you want to get the user name in the login controller.

If not so, feel free to disregard my answer.

You may have gotten it backward actually.

Success handler is somewhat like a custom implementation of "default-target-url".

So it is actually executed after login controller...

When login is successful, and there's no previously requested path (this is implemented by SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler) then the request will be sent to the "default-target-url".

Or when there's a custom success handler, the success handler will determine the path it goes to.